In D&D 2024, can a Paladin's Smite be counterspelled?
The D&D 2024 version of Paladin says:

Paladin’s Smite: You always have the Divine Smite spell prepared. In addition, you can cast it without expending a spell slot, but you must finish a Long Rest before you can cast it in this way again.

Does this mean it can now be prevented by a Counterspell?

Yes, it can
The Divine Smite spell says:

Level 1 Evocation (Paladin)
Casting Time: Bonus Action, which you take immediately after hitting a target with a Melee weapon or an Unarmed Strike
Range: Self
Component: V

And Counterspell says:

Casting Time: Reaction, which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of yourself casting a spell with Verbal, Somatic, or Material components

Since using Paladin's Smite now means you are casting the Divine Smite spell that has a Verbal component, and Counterspell can counter a spell if that spell has a Verbal component, you can counter it.
